# Mutation not committing state vuex - Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, nuxt.js

I am working on vuex app, on my other page i am committing changes to state its working, but here on this specific page i am getting some data from api and storing it in store but it get stuck in mutation, I am getting all data in mutation payload but its not effecting the changes, Please check the screenshot and code,

*I can not create fiddle cuz it works there*

**Getting Items**

```
async getItems () {
   await this.$axios.get(`/api/projects/w/latest/all`)
       .then(response => {
          this.$store.commit('project/UPDATE_PROJECTS', response.data.items)
        });
 }
```

**Action**

```
updateProjectsAction (context, projects) {
    context.commit('UPDATE_PROJECTS', projects)
},
```

**Mutation**

```
UPDATE_PROJECTS (state, payload ) {
    state.projects = payload
}
```

**State**

```
projects: {},
```

**Response**
[image]
[image]

When i click load state or manually commit these changes it gives me this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In getting items

```
this.$store.commit('project/UPDATE_PROJECTS', response.data.items)
```

you should change it to

```
this.$store.dispatch('project/updateProjectsAction', response.data.items)
```

In Action you should change

```
updateProjectsAction ({commit}, projects) {
commit('UPDATE_PROJECTS', projects)},
```

And last thing, you should have getters for getting data from vuex

```
getters:{
    getProjects: state =>{
          return state.project
  }
}
```

In .vue

```
import 'mapGetters' from 'vuex'
export default {
computed:{
       ...mapGetters({
           projects: project/getProjects
      })
   }
}
```

getters and computed will helps your vue app reactive

Comment: Thanks @DeadToy but still the same error "Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: undefined"

Comment: your axios return an Array but in state project is object, change project = []